# After photo is taken, OnActivityResult is not called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I'm trying to get the photo after it was taken but onActivityResult is not called:

```
public class questionListView extends LinearLayout {

protected static final Integer PICTURE_RESULT = 1;
private Context ctx;

public Uri path;

public questionListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ctx = context;
    init();
}

public questionListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    ctx = context;
    init();
}

private void init() {

    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View myView = factory.inflate(R.layout.view1, null);

    LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    myView.setLayoutParams(params);

    addView(myView);

    Button btaddphoto = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.btAddPhoto);

    btaddphoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String _path = Environment.getDataDirectory() + File.separator + "pic1.png";
            File file = new File(_path);
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

            ((Activity) ctx).startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);

        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Bitmap mBitmap;
    String _path = Environment.getDataDirectory() + File.separator + "pic1.png";
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path);
    if (mBitmap == null) {
        // bitmap still null
    } else {

        // kleine bitmap maken
        // deze in een imageview toevoegen aan layout lvPhotos

    }
}
```

}

I get an error in the line

```
super.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Error message:

```
The method onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) is undefined for the type LinearLayout
```

If I leave the out, the function onActivityResult is not called.

What am I doing wrong?

rg,
Eric

Comment: `onActivityResult` should be in your Activity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `onActivityResult()` from the `LinearLayout` class. The `onActivityResult()` method is specific to **Activities**.

For more details please see the official [Android developers site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) that treats this subject.

On a side note, it is a best practice to create your layouts from XML and not from Java code. Not only it is quicker to code, but also a lot faster in terms of performance.